# Danger of market orders

Tags: stocks, trading

As a new Day Trader, I have used market orders on several occasions (mainly to exit positions). But it occurred to me that there might be an inherent danger in doing so...

Let’s say that I want to sell a stock that currently is trading about $20. At the instant I execute the market order, the only buy order left is someone (nefarious) who wants to buy the stock at $0... Is there any safeguarding in place to prevent the order from being filled?

An extreme example, and only dangerous if there is low volume, but it could happen?

Comment: If B/A spreads are wide, you may see a crappy fill with a market order but for a stock that is  currently is trading at about $20, you're never going to see a market order filled anywhere near $0.  It's a bit further than far fetched. Some brokers permit self imposed limits on limit orders but that's a different story.

Answer (score 3):

There are various safeguards, depending on the exchange, and also depending on the broker and interface(s) you operate with. For stocks, a common safeguard is based on percentage from last price, or it may also be an absolute value based on the tick size. Sometimes it's also related to volatility (e.g. limits widen a few minutes before a scheduled interest rate announcement).

For a small time investor instead of worrying about such issues you can use Market-On-Open, Market-On-Close, and Immediate-Or-Cancel orders.